# How can I make sure the table is lined out correctly

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a table on my html page made by using angular but mainly HTMl & CSS (see the code snippets down below).
Because the tables are probably going to be rather large eventually, we wanted to make the table to be able to scroll. That itself, wasn't that big of a problem, and the table with only one value didn't cause any problems either.
After some fiddeling around the second table that has four values, did not want to work with me.

I have tried various lines of css that also have been used on the other table. It probably is something really simple that I just can't think of right now.

This is the table with only one value, and works just fine.

```
<table class="table table-hover table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Locaties</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let location of locations | filterPipeDep: searchToken">
        <td (click)="SpecificLocation(location.departmentId)">{{location.departmentName}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

table {
  -webkit-border-radius: 8px !important;
  -moz-border-radius: 8px !important;
  border-radius: 8px !important;
  background-color: rgba(245, 245, 245, 0.644);
  color: black;
}

thead {
  background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);
  color: black;
}

tbody {
  display: block;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
}

tr {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th{
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}
```

The table that doesn't work (and I did see the missing td and th class, but display block on every td and th with multiple rows isn't really a solution)

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>E-mail</th>
        <th>Voornaam</th>
        <th>Achternaam</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let user of users | filterPipeUsers: searchToken">
        <td (click)="SpecificUser(user.userId)">{{user.username}}</td>
        <td (click)="SpecificUser(user.userId)">{{user.firstName}}</td>
        <td (click)="SpecificUser(user.userId)">{{user.lastName}}</td>
        <td><a (click)="Debug()"><img class="delete"
              src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/controls-add-on-flat/48/Contols_-_Add_On-35-512.png" /></a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

table {
  -webkit-border-radius: 8px !important;
  -moz-border-radius: 8px !important;
  border-radius: 8px !important;
  background-color: rgba(245, 245, 245, 0.644);
  color: black;
}

thead {
  background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);
  color: black;
}

tbody {
  display: block;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
}

tr {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Like I said, it probably is something really simple I am just missing or overlooking. What I would like to see is the table being able to scroll down and up, with a fixed header, the text lined out and using 100% of the table with even widths.

Comment: Try to using inspect `(Ctrl+Shift+I)`. Then go to the console and check it

Comment: Try to recreate your problem as a code snippet. That way we can understand your question and eventually help you.